# How to debug GPS problems on Android 11

Tags: gps, android-11

I recently bought a `Realme 8 Pro` Phone with Android 11. To track my running course, I am using the app “Caynax Sports Tracker”. It did work for about 2 weeks without problem, receiving the GPS position. But after a while, the GPS signal was lost for more and more times. The last run lasted about 30 minutes, and GPS reception did work maybe for 2 minutes! On the same evening, no GPS signal was found whatsoever.

To fix this problem, I tried to use the following apps:

- GPS Aid - Fix GPS Problems (TechRCS)
- GPS Reset COM - GPS Repair, Navigation & GPS info (DS Software)
- GPS Status & Toolbox (MobiWIA Kft.)

These apps seem to reset the GPS, clear GPS data, download GPS data, etc. Yesterday evening I tried for an hour to fix the GPS problems, also restarted the device, but I was not able to get a single GPS fix.

On the next morning, without any change, it seemed to have worked again.

Is there a way I can see where the problem is? Is it a hardware problem, software problem, a `realme` problem or a problem with android? Maybe there is an app which can debug a bit more?

Comment: One action most users forget is still available: Shutdown your phone for a minute. Do not reboot, really shut it down. Then the GPS chip will be cut from power which is like a hard reset for it. On my phone I had the case where GPS wasn't able to get a fix with any of the 24 available satellites with clear view into the sky. Only a shutdown was able to fix this problem.

Comment: Ah thanks, I surely will try that.

Comment: I'm too facing the same problem (Realme x2 pro), really anoying and random, it only started after the android  11 update. Tried several times to get help from realme, but they didn't care to help! I regret buying a realme